# Why does ArchLinux keep some users/groups after package uninstallation?

Tags: files, permissions, arch-linux, security, users

I've noticed that after uninstalling the `postgresql` package in ArchLinux the `postgres` user and group are not removed automatically. The same is true for some other packages. Investigating this further, I've come across this [page](https://www.archlinux.org/todo/usergroup-management/), which states:

> The packages listed here use `userdel`/`groupdel` to remove the user they
>   created. These should never be removed automatically as it poses a
>   security risk if any files are left behind with this ownership.

I wonder why leaving files with this ownership poses a security risk?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a security risk because file ownership in the FS is stored not by symbolic name, but by UID and GID. If a user is removed and files remain owned by that user, they become inaccessible under owner permission. However, if a different user is later created that is allocated the same UID, that user will gain ownership of the files. This is potentially a security risk because of the various ways in which file ownership is used as a security mechanism; the simplest form is that where confidential information (e.g. SSH keys in `id_rsa` and so forth, wi-fi authentication information in `wpa_supplicant.conf`) could be leaked to the new user.

Comment: In addition, the new user can also be at risk, if any of the old user's executable files are setuid or use suEXEC in such a way that an unauthorized user can run programs as that user.